# Power series of z/sin(z)?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

So I need to compute the coefficient of the $z^4$ in the power series of $\frac{z}{\sin z}$.

I tried differentiating the function and obtaining coefficients like in Taylor's expansions but had a really hard time. In general I'm finding it extremely hard to obtain the power series of various complex functions, especially with something like $\sin z$ in the denominator. Any tips / tricks?

Comment: We have $\frac{z}{\sin(z)} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \ldots} = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x + x^2 + \ldots$ where $x = \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} + \ldots$. Since $x^3 = \frac{z^6}{6^3} + ($higher order) we only need to compute the first three terms $1+x+x^2$ to order $z^4$.

Comment: That's really neat! So this is a general trick to obtain power series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple method that works well to find the first few terms in the power-series.

We first expand the denominator in a power-series around $z=0$: $$\frac{z}{\sin(z)} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \ldots}$$

This has the form of a geometrical series $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x + x^2 + \ldots$ for $x = \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} + \mathcal{O}(z^6)$. The expansion above holds as long as $|x|<1$ which is the case for all $z$ sufficiently close to $z=0$ (which is all we need).

Expanding the different terms $x^k$ is a power-series in $z$ we find

$$\begin{align}x^2 &= \left(\frac{z^2}{3!}\right)^2 - 2\frac{z^2}{3!}\frac{z^4}{5!} + \mathcal{O}(z^8)\\x^3 &= \left(\frac{z^2}{3!}\right)^3 + \mathcal{O}(z^8)\end{align}$$

The term $x^n$ will only give rise to terms of order $z^{2n}$ and larger so to get the series to order $z^6$ we can stop at $x^3$. Adding up all the terms above gives

$$\frac{z}{\sin(z)} = 1 + \frac{z^2}{6} + \frac{7z^4}{360} + \frac{31z^6}{15120} + \mathcal{O}(z^8)$$